# IllegalStateException when running a Selenium test

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm getting an `IllegalStateException` thrown when running the following code:

```java
package newprojectss;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Tours {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\selenium-2.25.0\\chromedriver_win32");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
        String actualTitle = "";

        // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        // get the actual value of the title
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        /*
         * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
         * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
         */
        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }

        //close Firefox
        driver.close();

     }
}
```

What can cause the problem?

Comment: Why are you running selenium as a console app?

Answer (score 0):

illegalstateexception occurs because the chrome driver is not set properly

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\selenium-2.25.0\\chromedriver_win32")
```

Chrome driver path doesn't point till chromedriver.exe file

Unzip your driver folder and point the location till chromedriver.exe

Eg: C://Users//username//Desktop//chromedriver.exe